# RSA Encryption Failed with Error Code = -2146893819

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, genuinechannels

I'm working on some code that dropped on me when another developer (and the only person who knew anything about this system) left. I'm trying to figure out why my client and server are not connecting. I'm getting the following error:

"Genuine channels operation exception: The connection has been forcibly closed.
Specified reason: RSA encryption failed with error code = -2146893819"

Initial google research seems to indicate that Genuine Channels is a communications library that was being used (but I'm not sure if that's accurate). Also, there doesn't seem to be any information on what that particular error code means.

At this point, I'm fine with suggestions on where to give my research if you don't have any concrete ideas on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error code -2146893819 is hex 80090005 which, in the MS crypto libraries, is `NTE_BAD_DATA`.

That's about as far as I got before I lost interest (that tends to happen to me a lot with crypto stuff) and it's only slightly more helpful than what you've got, so I've made it community wiki.

You haven't actually stated what you were doing when you got the error but the top hit for `"rsa"` and `"nte_bad_data"` on Google was [this](http://netpl.blogspot.com/2009/01/ntebaddata-0x80090005-on-cryptimportkey.html).

Still, it expands you Google search terms at least :-)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank for the insight.

I wish I knew more about what was going on at this point so I could ask better questions, but at least I've got a few more strands to pull at. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For reference to future people who visit this question, I eventually solved this issue. It turned out to be a a DLL mismatch between the versions of GenuineChannels & our cryptology implementation that were on our client machines and our server machines.